# CancellationToken leaking memory

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cancellationtokensource

I have a timer that starts 2 tasks every 2 seconds... I keep track of those taks in a simple list, (so I can wait for them to complete when I stop the app).

The tasks effectively go to the database, run a couple of updates and complete.
The tasks themselves never take more than a second to run

```
...
// global variables to keep track of the running tasks.
List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();
CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

// in the timer function
private void Timer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  _tasks.Add( Foo1Async(_cts.Token) );
  _tasks.Add( Foo2Async(_cts.Token) );
  // remove the completed ones
  _tasks.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);
}
...
```

After a few minutes the memory goes from 40Mb to 130Mb, (and climbing) ...

If I replace **only** the code below and **and nothing else**

```
...
  _tasks.Add( Foo1Async( CancellationToken.None)) );
  _tasks.Add( Foo2Async( CancellationToken.None)) );
...
```

The memory remains at a steady 40Mb and never increases.

A couple of points

- I don't cancel any tasks during my test, (they all run to completion).
- I don't throw any exceptions during my test.
- The database I use is Sqlite
- During boths tests I do exactly the same work, the only difference is the CancellationToken used.
- The memory never seems to be released, even if I wait a long time.
- The timer is a `System.Timers.Timer` and I only re-start it once the timer event has been processed.
- I do not us any other tokens, (or token source)
- I do not register for any token cancellation.

If I take a memory snapshot the number of `CancellationCallbackInfo` seem to be the issue, but I have no idea where they come from and how to release them.

Looking at the .NET source code, the callbacks are used in `CancellationTokenSource` but I am not really sure how more are added to it, (or how to free them).

Any suggestions as to what could cause the memory leak when I use `_cts.Token` vs when I use `CancellationToken.None`

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? Specially interested in `Foo1Async`/`Foo2Async` and how they use the token, but if you can add the whole test, that's better

Comment: Hum, I will try, but unfortunately this would involve opening a Sqlite Database, loading data, doing some work on it and so on... I will try and see if I can remove the database work.

Comment: I forgot to add, how the tokens are used. But basically, when I do a db read `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` and I propagate the exception. But no exceptions are ever thrown, (the tasks are never cancelled).

Comment: Do Foo1Async or Foo2Async pass the token into other asynchronous methods further downstream? Is it possible that those are calling Register, even though you are not? Quartz.NET had a [similar issue](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/600) and [realized](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/commit/23d8f5211bfea92353221e6e0d0467f874f8ca9b) that they were passing it to downstream methods they didn't mean to pass it to.

Comment: "unfortunately this would involve opening a Sqlite Database, loading data, doing some work on it and so on" - yes, asking an answerable quite often requires the asker to put in some solid effort. We're happy to help, but we need the [mcve] to do so.

Comment: @SimonGoodman - I'm particularly interested in seeing a full example as I think this problem is a perfect fit for Microsoft's Reactive Framework. I can't tell for sure or provide you with a good answer until I see the [mcve].

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, makes sense, the only functions I pass the token(s) to are from the SQLite .NET library. (https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), thankfully their code is open source so I can look into it further, (or use the  non-async calls for testing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is/was an issue in some of the .NET DBCommand code, the async functions register for cancellation, but would only dispose if there is an exception. As you noticed in most cases it would just grow the list.

This issue was fixed sometime [last year in .NET core v2.x](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/297fcc33db4e65287455f6575684f24975688b53), (not sure if it ever will be fixed in .NET standard, I am using 4.6.1 and it still is an issue).

One way I worked around it was by writing my own wrapper around the async functions I needed.

You could also call the non-async functions, (but you lose the 'cancel' functionality that the async functions give you).

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue indeed with my `ExecuteReaderAsync`, I just replaced it with `ExecuteReader` as my calls are very fast and I check for cancellation right afterwards.

Comment: I would suggest you update your title as it is DBCommand that's leaking resources...