# Memory leak when using async/await with CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.6, cancellationtokensource

I have inherited an app and investigating it for memory leak issues. It's a C# .NET Framework 4.6 application that uses a lot of async/await. I think the issue is because of the thread is not being cancelled after completion of each tasks but I need help to figure out the fix.

There are a lot of nested functions inside, some are passing the `cancellationToken` and some are not. ex: those db functions `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`, `SaveChangesAsync()`

In the memory profiler. I see a lot of objects like `SQLParameter`, `_SQLMetaData` that keeps on accumulating.

---

- This is what VS's Diagnostic Tools shows after using `CancellationToken` on the `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`:

  - The first row is memory usage before querying the db for the first time.
  - The second row is after 300 runs.
  - The third row shows memory usage after 600 runs.
  - [image: Memory Profiler screenshot]
- This is what VS's Diagnostic Tools shows when I **don't** pass the `CancellationToken` into the `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`:

  - The rows correspond to 0, 300, 600, and 900 runs.
  - [image: Memory Profiler screenshot]

---

the code goes like this:

```
    public class Jobsstore
    {
            async Task<Guid?> getjobID(CancellationToken ct)
            {
                //query the jobs table if there's a scheduled job and get the GUID
                //didn't pass the cancellationtoken
                jobHeader = await dbContext.Tbl_Jobs.Where(<criteria>).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)
                
                    if(jobHeader != null)
                    {
                        jobHeader.LastGeneratorPickupDateTime = now;
                        jobHeader.UpdateDateTime = now;
                        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        return jobHeader.GUID;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
            }
    }
    
    public class ServerClass
    {
    
        public async Task Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken){
            while (false == cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    _jobID = await Jobsstore.getjobID(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false); //Calls a funciton to get JobID & updates the database
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log Error
                }
                if (!_jobID.HasValue)
                {
                    //If no jobs then wait
                    await Task.Delay(xxx).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    continue;
                }
                
                try
                {
                    //do I need to pass the cancellationToken to each of these functions?
                    await validation1().ConfigureAwait(false); //call a function that will read the db
                    await validation2().ConfigureAwait(false); //call a function that will read the db
                    await apicall().ConfigureAwait(false); //call a function that will POST to an external API
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Log Error
                    await Task.Delay(xxx).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Simple
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ServerClass.Start(cancellationSource.Token).Wait();
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: Could you include in the question the `getjobID` method? We need to see how the token is used inside.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias updated. I tried to simplify it as much as I can.

Comment: So the token is passed only to the `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(ct)` method. Could you remove it from there, and see if it makes any difference? You could also experiment by passing [`CancellationToken.None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none) as argument to the `Start` method. My guess is that the memory leak problem is not caused by the token.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the memory leak is lesser if I pass CancellationToken.None to dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(ct)

Comment: I am not sure that I can help you, but in case someone else can, could you provide some metrics? How much memory is leaking with `cancellationSource.Token`, and how much with `CancellationToken.None`?

Comment: **Exactly what** makes you think you have a memory-leak? Simply using hundreds of MB of RAM **is normal** today: the .NET CLR on x64 uses _a lot_ of memory because of too many reasons to list. Have you run actual memory-leak-detection tools - or at least a profiler?

Comment: @Dai I'm using VS diagnostic tools. I've attached an image link. It's not normal

Comment: @Yoshimori Your screenshot shows **11MB** GC heap memory usage... what's the problem? (And 80% of that 11MB will likely be Entity Framework btw: it allocates _a lot_ of strings and hashsets and other objects when it first-loads and it keeps in all in-memory and is used by all the `DbContext` instances).

Comment: @Dai yes and it keeps on increasing until the server runs out of memory. GC doesn't clear it even if I call GC.Collect

Comment: So what's inside your heap snapshot when the server runs out of memory then?

Comment: @Yoshimori I think the problem might relate to the lifespan of your `DbContext` - where and for-how-long do you keep each `DbContext` instance around for? I note that `DbContext` is meant to be short-lived (i.e. it's a unit-of-work) so you shouldn't keep an instance of `DbContext` stored in a long-lived object field: the lifespan of a `DbContext` should be a single-method.

Comment: lots of cancellationcallbackinfo. looks like this is my issue and workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642225/cancellationtoken-leaking-memory

Comment: So you have a very long running `while()` loop? IMHO you should, create a new context  and dispose it in that loop.